# CMake OS X CLion. How to link a custom dynamic library?

Tags: c++, macos, cmake

Probably this question was asked several times. But I can't find a solution. I try to link a shared library and add it to RPATH. I tried several solutions:

Here is my Cmake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(Cpp)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

file(GLOB CPP_UTILS CppUtils/*.cpp CppUtils/*.h)
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp ${CPP_UTILS})
add_executable(Cpp ${SOURCE_FILES})

SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE)

target_link_libraries(Cpp /Users/mac/Projects/ECMCalmnessScroreAlgo/Cpp/libs/libpython3.7m.dylib)

include_directories(Include)
```

And it outputs the following error in runtime:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libpython3.7m.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/mac/Projects/ECMCalmnessScroreAlgo/Cpp/cmake-build-debug/Cpp
  Reason: image not found
```

Temporary I just want link a custom library, to understand how it works. Then I want to copy the libs folder while build execution.

This is what it outputs when I try to run the command manually make VERBOSE=1

```
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/bin/cmake -H/Users/mac/Projects/ECMCalmnessScroreAlgo/Cpp -B/Users/mac/Projects/ECMCalmnessScroreAlgo/Cpp/cmake-build-debug --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /Users/mac/Projects/ECMCalmnessScroreAlgo/Cpp/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles /Users/mac/Projects/ECMCalmnessScroreAlgo/Cpp/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/Cpp.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/Cpp.dir/depend
cd /Users/mac/Projects/ECMCalmnessScroreAlgo/Cpp/cmake-build-debug && /Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /Users/mac/Projects/ECMCalmnessScroreAlgo/Cpp /Users/mac/Projects/ECMCalmnessScroreAlgo/Cpp /Users/mac/Projects/ECMCalmnessScroreAlgo/Cpp/cmake-build-debug /Users/mac/Projects/ECMCalmnessScroreAlgo/Cpp/cmake-build-debug /Users/mac/Projects/ECMCalmnessScroreAlgo/Cpp/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/Cpp.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/Cpp.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/Cpp.dir/build
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `CMakeFiles/Cpp.dir/build'.
[100%] Built target Cpp
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /Users/mac/Projects/ECMCalmnessScroreAlgo/Cpp/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles 0
yo:cmake-build-debug stikhonenko$ make clean
yo:cmake-build-debug stikhonenko$ make VERBOSE=1
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/bin/cmake -H/Users/mac/Projects/ECMCalmnessScroreAlgo/Cpp -B/Users/mac/Projects/ECMCalmnessScroreAlgo/Cpp/cmake-build-debug --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /Users/mac/Projects/ECMCalmnessScroreAlgo/Cpp/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles /Users/mac/Projects/ECMCalmnessScroreAlgo/Cpp/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/Cpp.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/Cpp.dir/depend
cd /Users/mac/Projects/ECMCalmnessScroreAlgo/Cpp/cmake-build-debug && /Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /Users/mac/Projects/ECMCalmnessScroreAlgo/Cpp /Users/mac/Projects/ECMCalmnessScroreAlgo/Cpp /Users/mac/Projects/ECMCalmnessScroreAlgo/Cpp/cmake-build-debug /Users/mac/Projects/ECMCalmnessScroreAlgo/Cpp/cmake-build-debug /Users/mac/Projects/ECMCalmnessScroreAlgo/Cpp/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/Cpp.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/Cpp.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/Cpp.dir/build
[ 25%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Cpp.dir/main.cpp.o
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++    -I/Users/mac/Projects/ECMCalmnessScroreAlgo/Cpp/Include  -g -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk   -std=gnu++11 -o CMakeFiles/Cpp.dir/main.cpp.o -c /Users/mac/Projects/ECMCalmnessScroreAlgo/Cpp/main.cpp
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Cpp.dir/CppUtils/System.cpp.o
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++    -I/Users/mac/Projects/ECMCalmnessScroreAlgo/Cpp/Include  -g -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk   -std=gnu++11 -o CMakeFiles/Cpp.dir/CppUtils/System.cpp.o -c /Users/mac/Projects/ECMCalmnessScroreAlgo/Cpp/CppUtils/System.cpp
[ 75%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Cpp.dir/CppUtils/TimeUtils.cpp.o
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++    -I/Users/mac/Projects/ECMCalmnessScroreAlgo/Cpp/Include  -g -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk   -std=gnu++11 -o CMakeFiles/Cpp.dir/CppUtils/TimeUtils.cpp.o -c /Users/mac/Projects/ECMCalmnessScroreAlgo/Cpp/CppUtils/TimeUtils.cpp
[100%] Linking CXX executable Cpp
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/Cpp.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++   -g -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names  CMakeFiles/Cpp.dir/main.cpp.o CMakeFiles/Cpp.dir/CppUtils/System.cpp.o CMakeFiles/Cpp.dir/CppUtils/TimeUtils.cpp.o  -o Cpp ../libs/libpython3.7m.dylib 
[100%] Built target Cpp
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /Users/mac/Projects/ECMCalmnessScroreAlgo/Cpp/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles 0
```

Comment: CLion does it for me. This is the command I see in console
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/bin/cmake --build /Users/mac/Projects/ECMCalmnessScroreAlgo/Cpp/cmake-build-debug --target Cpp -- -j 4

Comment: Is `/Users/mac/Projects/ECMCalmnessScroreAlgo/Cpp/libs/libpython3.7m.dylib` actually a symlink to `/usr/local/lib/libpython3.7m.dylib`? Does original file exists when you run the executable? @keith: There is nothing to install here.

Comment: This is the original file. And it exists in the source directory

Comment: Hmm, then why error message tells about **different file**...

Comment: I think it tries to find the library in another location then the link location

Comment: Is `/usr/local/lib/libpython3.7m.dylib` file exists?

Comment: Is /usr/local/lib/libpython3.7m.dylib file exists? No

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159771/discussion-between-semyon-tikhonenko-and-tsyvarev).

Answer (score 2):

You first need to tell cmake where to *find* the library ([`find_library`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_library.html)), and only then you can use the result from `find_library` in `target_link_libraries`

`find_library` takes a `PATHS` argument which you can use to tell cmake where to look

```
find_library(
    PYTHON_3 
    libpython3.7m 
    PATHS
        /Users/mac/Projects/ECMCalmnessScroreAlgo/Cpp/libs)
```

Now you will have a variable `${PYTHON_3}` which contains the path to the library. You use that variable in `target_link_libraries`

```
target_link_libraries(
    Cpp
    ${PYTHON_3})
```

Here is the complete `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(Cpp)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

file(GLOB CPP_UTILS CppUtils/*.cpp CppUtils/*.h)
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp ${CPP_UTILS})
add_executable(Cpp ${SOURCE_FILES})

SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE)

find_library(
    PYTHON_3 
    libpython3.7m 
    PATHS
        /Users/mac/Projects/ECMCalmnessScroreAlgo/Cpp/libs)

target_link_libraries(Cpp ${PYTHON_3})
target_include_directories(Cpp Include)
```

Comment: It outputs:
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
PYTHON_3
    linked by target "Cpp" in directory /Users/mac/Projects/ECMCalmnessScroreAlgo/Cpp

Comment: So cmake is telling you that it can't find `libpython3.7m` in the location `/Users/mac/Projects/ECMCalmnessScroreAlgo/Cpp/libs`. Are you sure you have the library available there?

Comment: I changed libpython3.7m to libpython3.7m.dylib. And now it outputs the same error as before:
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libpython3.7m.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/mac/Projects/ECMCalmnessScroreAlgo/Cpp/cmake-build-debug/Cpp
  Reason: image not found

Comment: Have you tried linking statically? Try add `set(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ${CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_SUFFIX})` before the call to `find_library`

Comment: Please also post the output of `make VERBOSE=1` when you try build

Comment: I linked to a static library successfully, but i want to link to a dynamic library.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159772/discussion-between-semyon-tikhonenko-and-steve-lorimer).

Answer (score 0):

Lets try linking the library's directory!

Assuming the name of your library is `libpython3`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(Cpp)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)



file(GLOB CPP_UTILS CppUtils/*.cpp CppUtils/*.h)
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp ${CPP_UTILS})
add_executable(Cpp ${SOURCE_FILES})

SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE)


LINK_DIRECTORIES(/Users/mac/Projects/ECMCalmnessScroreAlgo/Cpp/libs)

target_link_libraries(Cpp libpython3.7m)

include_directories(Include)
```

Does this work? :-)

Comment: No it fails while compilation: ld: library not found for -llibpython3.7m. I tried this solution before.

Comment: Oh, interesting! I wonder if Steve's answer will work here? A chance for both of us to learn!